# SQL Server Query issue, unable to crack the logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have data as below in two tables in MS SQL Server.

**Table 1**

| id | name | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | 12000 |
| 111 | Mary | 1000 |
| 222 | King | 1400 |
| 333 | Queen | 800 |
| 444 | David | 900 |
| 555 | Hope | 560 |
| 666 | Lucy | 1150 |
| 777 | Martha | 1290 |
| 456 | Nancy | 1300 |
| 654 | Stoney | 1050 |
| 345 | Daniel | 950 |

**Table 2**

| CID | cid_addon |
| --- | --- |
| 123;111 | xasd |
| 222;333 | aweqwr |
| 444;666;777;345 | weriwer |
| 555;545;675 | sgsfds |

CID field in Table 2 can contain number of ids separated by ;. I need to print name and salary from Table 1 for ids which are available in table under cid.
for eg: i can print mary & john as both of these ids are available in Table 2 under CID.
I cannot print 555:Hope as in table 2 CID column has 555;545;675 out of which 675& 545 are not available in Table 1.

i tried to split CID into individual values using string split but im not sure how to build logic to find if all elements in CID exist to be able to print values from Table 1.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Are both table1 and table2 sample table data? We need the expected result too, i.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and SQL [Window function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to get the results you need.

Step 1. Cross apply STRING_SPLIT() on cid columns and unnest it to one cid per row.

Step 2. [Left JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) unnested_table2(cid table) with table1 (id table) on unnested id.

Step 3. Use window funcion to find out the cid with some id whose salary info are missing.

Step 4. Filter out the cid with some id's  missing salary info and display those with all id's salary info.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e25c6/11):

```
with cid_data_with_id_info AS (
SELECT
    cid,
    id,
    name,
    salary,
    sum(case when t1.id is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cid) as num_not_found_cid
FROM
    (SELECT cid, cast (value as int) as cid_part
    FROM tbl2 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CID, ';')
    ) unnested_t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbl1 t1
ON
    t1.id = unnested_t2.cid_part
)
SELECT
    cid,
    id,
    name,
    salary
FROM
    cid_data_with_id_info
where
    num_not_found_cid = 0
```

| cid | id | name | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123;111 | 123 | John | 12000 |
| 123;111 | 111 | Mary | 1000 |
| 222;333 | 222 | King | 1400 |
| 222;333 | 333 | Queen | 800 |
| 444;666;777;345 | 444 | David | 900 |
| 444;666;777;345 | 666 | Lucy | 1150 |
| 444;666;777;345 | 777 | Martha | 1290 |
| 444;666;777;345 | 345 | Daniel | 950 |